How do I configure passing a token to the Authorization header for a authenticated access request in fastAPI?
I have a request that requires an authenticated access
`@router.get("/profile/")
async def get_base_page(request: Request, current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("profile.html", {"request": request,
                                                       "name": current_user.name})`

to get current user I use token from Authorization header, as far as I undertood an oauth2 system.
`oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth")


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    user = await users_utils.get_user_by_token(token)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    return user`

this is my auth and get_user_by_token method from my code above
`@router.post("/auth", response_model=TokenBase)
async def auth(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = await users_utils.get_user_by_email(email=form_data.username)

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect email or password")

    if not users_utils.validate_password(
        password=form_data.password, hashed_password=user["hashed_password"]
    ):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect email or password")

    token = await users_utils.create_user_token(user_id=user["id"])
    return {"access_token": token['token'], "token_type": "bearer"}`

`async def get_user_by_token(token: str):
    query = tokens_table.join(users_table).select().where(
        and_(
            tokens_table.c.token == token,
            tokens_table.c.expires > datetime.now()
        )
    )
    return await database.fetch_one(query)`

To get the html input data I use another request "/pages/get-login-data"
`@router.post("/get-login-data")
async def login_user(
    request: Request,
    email: EmailStr = Form(...),
    password: str = Form(...)
):
    user_data = UserLogin(email=email, password=password)
    await auth(user_data) #imported method above

    return templates.TemplateResponse("auth.html", {"request": request, "message": "User logib successfully!"})`

let me know if i need to provide more code
